# vi to vim upgrade on ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: 10.04

I am currently using UBUNTU 10.04 LTS on a pc connected to a server meant for running Molecular Dynamics and Monte-Carlo simulation using LAMMPS. I don't have any prior experience working on vi editor but from what I have heard from other users is that vim have some added advantage over vi.
So, what I want to ask whether vi is mapped into vim in ubuntu 10.04 LTS?
If not , how can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly vim is not installed by default. From a shell try :

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

it will either install it (and map it to vi) or let you know that is already installed